# Orthogonality in $H^1(T)$ with the inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)_{L^2(T)}$

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Take the Sobolev space 
$$H^1(T)=\left\{f \in L^2(T) ~|~ f' \in L^2(T)\right\}$$ 
where $T$ is the 1-torus (that is a circle) and $f'$ the weak derivative.  Take then a function $v\in H^1(T)$ and define for every $f,g\in H^1(T)$ the $L^2(T)$-inner-product
$$(f,g)_{L^2(T)}:= \int_T f\cdot g ~d\mu $$
and the $H^1(T)$-inner-product
$$(f,g)_{H^1(T)}:= (f,g)_{L^2(T)} + (f',g')_{L^2(T)} $$
where $d\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and $f'$ and $g'$ are the weak derivatives.

The question is the following: it is possible to find a function $w\in H^1(T)$ that is orthogonal to $v$ in the sense of the $L^2(T)$-inner-product, but it is not orthogonal to $v$ in the sense of the 
$H^1(T)$-inner-product?
In case, can you exhibit a counterexample or prove that it is not possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $v \in H^1(T)$ is not essentially constant and $\int_T v \neq 0$. Define $a=-\frac{\int_T v^2}{\int_T v}$. Then $v$ and $a+v$ are orthogonal in $L^2$ (check it) but not in $H^1$ (the derivatives are equal everywhere, so the inner product is the integral of a nonnegative function which is nonzero on a set of positive measure).

The first assumption is essential: among essentially constant functions the $H^1$ inner product reduces to the $L^2$ inner product. I don't know whether the second assumption is essential (though I doubt it).

Comment: I believe the OP is giving you some function $\nu$ and asking you to find a function orthogonal to it in $L^2$ but not in $H^1$.

Comment: @uniquesolution I've edited, in particular adapting to the situation of being on the circle.